# Is there an easy way to broadcast many new columns onto a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a set of `.png` images, as well as a `df_train` data frame that has 2 columns, the names of the image files `id_code` and a `diagnosis` for the image. (`df_train` has `m` rows and `2` columns)

I would like to create a new data frame `df_train_new` that maintains the `m` rows, but adds `n` new columns. Every new column in `n` would hold one of that image's pixel values. (`df_train_new` has `m` rows and `(2+n)` columns).

I have written simple code via `PIL` to take the pixel values of the green channel, vectorized them (so they are n rows and 1 column), and have tried to create a for loop (looping over every image) to add these new columns to the new data frame.

```py
df_train = pd.read_csv('../train.csv')

img_dims = 6869376 # number of pixels per image

for example in range(len(df_train)): # iterate over every image
    img = Image.open("../input/train_images/" + str(df_train.iloc[example,0]) + ".png") # open image with PIL
    img_green_data = np.asarray(list(img.getdata()))[:,1].reshape(img_dims,-1).T # create (1, 6869376) vector for every image
    df_train.loc[example,2:] = img_green_data # now try to add these columns to the data frame! *** doesn't work
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray

I understand this must not be the right way to do it, but I've toyed with a few ways and feel like there must be a much easier way to do this kind of thing!

Comment: You say that the dimensions of `img_green_data` are (1, 6869376) (though you might want to check).  What are the dimensions of `df_train[example]`?

Comment: df_train[example] dimensions are (1, 2)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than updating the existing data frame consider building a Numpy matrix by vertically stacking from a list of pixel matrices. Then, concatenate original data frame with casted matrix. Below is an untested adjustment.

```
df_train = pd.read_csv('../train.csv')

img_dims = 6869376 # number of pixels per image

mat_list = []
# iterate over every image
for id_code in df_train['id_code']):
    # open image with PIL
    img = Image.open("../input/train_images/" + str(id_code) + ".png")
    # create (1, 6869376) vector for every image
    img_green_data = (np.asarray(list(img.getdata()))[:,1]
                        .reshape(img_dims,-1)
                        .transpose()
                     )
    # APPEND TO LIST
    mat_list.append(img_green_data)

final_df = pd.concat([df_train,
                      pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(mat_list))],
                     axis = 'columns')
```